# Automatic translation of C# enum to JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, reflection, code-translation

I have a flags enumeration in a .NET assembly that is getting called from an ASP.NET page. I want to have a Visual Studio build step generate a `.js` file that has the JavaScript equivalent in it. Are there any tools for doing this?

---

*edit:* This seems to work.

```
public class JavaScriptReflection
{
    public static string Go(Type type)
    {
        if (!type.IsEnum) return;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("var {0} = {{ ", type.Name);

        foreach (FieldInfo fInfo in 
            type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))

            sb.AppendFormat("{0}:{1},\r\n", 
                fInfo.Name,
                fInfo.GetRawConstantValue().ToString());

        sb.Append("};");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would +1 your edit it it were an answer. It seems like the right tool for the job in a UNIX program kind of way.

Answer (score 1):

[Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp) is one thing to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I've had sucess recently using reflection on output assembly files to generate code.

Try using something like this in a console app you can call from your post-build process:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("FileName");
Type myEnumType = assembly.GetType("EnumName");
foreach(MemberInfo mi in myEnumType.GetMembers().Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field))
        Console.WriteLine(mi.Name);
```

Comment: Why not use `Enum.GetValues(myEnumType)` instead??

Comment: You mean Enum.GetNames(). Yes, that would be simpler in this case. The OP question was trying to use reflection though, so I gave the method of accessing enum values via reflection.

Comment: ^ And BTW, you'd still have to use reflection to get the enum type in this scenario since you're loading an external assembly to generate code. It is just the `.GetMembers().Where(m => m.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)` that would get replaced.

Comment: I have no argument about the first 2 lines that loads the type (That is why I used the same variable name that you wrote). You should use `Enum.GetNames` or `Enum.GetValues` instead of that foreach. And if you need both names and values (which is in most cases), `Enum.GetNames` will result in using `Enum.Parse` for each name, but  by using `Enum.GetValues`, You have the names (`.ToString()`) and values together

Comment: It depends on the code being generated. You might need the values, but I would advise against for things like a URL parameters because an integral value is less readable. You get a lot more data with the MemberInfo. When using reflection to generate code you often need to look at custom attributes as well, for example using the `System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute` you can pull a label to be shown to the user--this is something I almost always end up doing when generating code from enums for web clients, and you can't do using any of the `Enum` static methods.